# Syntax Error on Select and Option Tag

Tags: php, html

So I have this code in me. I used an `option` tag that will `echo` all of the database's value in a `select` tag (drop down menu). What I want is that upon selecting an item, I want it to stay in the dropdown menu until I choose another one. So the only applicable answer is to add an attribute to the `option` tag which is `selected="selected"`. Right? I somehow get a syntax error on placing the quotations. I know this is a noob question. Apparently I'm training myself to PHP. Could you please help me with this? Here is my code:

```
echo "<option value = '".$row['brandname']."'>" .$row['brandname'] . "</option>";
```

So where should I place the `selected` attribute there? Any help? By the way, I'm using the `onchange ="this.form.submit()"`.

Comment: Are you getting values from database

Comment: oh by the way again.. when i choose an item.. my database is loading..which is good.. but once i chose an item..it always gets back to the first option item.. and not stopping from what item i chose..

Comment: yes..im getting values from the database.. i just need to know where should i put the selected="selected" attribute there.. it gives me syntax error.. lol

Comment: I had corrected the capitalization mistakes, improved grammar and removed thanks note from the content. I had also removed language name from title as it is not required due to the presence of tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
echo "<option selected value = '".$row['brandname']."'>" .$row['brandname'] . "</option>";
```

Comment: i tried it sir.. but it gone backwards.. instead of the first option.. it always selects the last option.. :D lol sorry.. complete newbie here...

Comment: I thought you knew exactly which _option_ to select :P If its selecting the last one this means you are setting the _selected_ option on all the _option_ elements within the loop. Use an _if_ condition to set the _selected_ attribute *only* if the element is the first element of the loop, it should work :)

Comment: Your welcome :) Do select mark as answer if it helped you out, thnx :)

Answer (score 0):

`echo "<option value = '".$row['brandname']."' selected='selected'>" .$row['brandname'] . "</option>";`

or you can selects options by JQuery after completion of running PHP script at client side

**your php output .html file**

`<select class='list_brand'>
<?php 
     foreach($brandobj as $row){
     echo "<option value = '".$row['brandname']."'>" .$row['brandname'] . "</option>";
     }
?>
</select>`

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

`<script>
    $('.list_brand option[value='brand-to-select']).attr('selected','selected');
</script>`